Помогите открыть файл с расширением .p на Mac
Есть файл с расщирением .p и я не могу понять то ли в нём ошибка, то ли нужен специальный метод чтобы открыть правильно этот файл. Подскажите пожалуйста как извлечь информацию отсюда: v3_0_ab_susp.p

pickle.load вроде прекрасно отрабатывает, в чём проблема?

Очень похоже, что этоn файл - сериализованный через pickle объект Numpy.
Соответственно этот файл нужно передать в метод load
numpy_obj = pickle.load("file name")

